# iPhone app detecting wifi network while running in the background

Tags: iphone, ios4, background-process, reachability

does anyone know if there is a way for an iPhone app to continuously detect the presence of WiFi networks while running in the background? What are the limitations?

Cheers,
 Marko

Comment: Apple would definitely not want you to do this, since it's already done by the os. You *can* check what type of internet connectivity you have, if any.

Comment: but you are saying that you are not able to see the details (ssid for example) of surrounding wifi networks?

Answer (score 0):

you can see all the details(all SSID, RSSI) of nearby WIFI hotspots but i dont know how to inject this code so that i can run on BG